# Как изменить вывод поля формы в Django (Добавить свой кверисет в поле)

Tags: python, django

У меня есть модель Placement для расстановки кораблей на поле игрока (делаю что-то типо морского боя на Джанге) Есть форма , где мы выводим все поля, кроме юзера (он добавится после сборки данных с формы, т.к нужно доставать ip адрес). Мне нужно, когда юзер выберет корабль из формы и нажмет на кнопку "Выставить", данный корабль должен пропасть из селектора формы. Как это можно сделать

Собственно сам код:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from users.models import CustomUser


class Ships(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Название корабля', max_length=67)
    length = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Длина корабля в клетках', default=1)
    max_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Максимальное кол-во едениц на доске', default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Корабль'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Корабли'
        ordering = ('length', )


class Positions(models.Model):

    VERTICAL = 'vertical'
    HORIZONTAL = 'horizontal'

    POSITIONS = (
        (VERTICAL, 'Вертикально'),
        (HORIZONTAL, 'Горизонтально')
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, verbose_name='Пользователь', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ship = models.ForeignKey(Ships, verbose_name='Корабль', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ship_position')
    x_pos = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Позиция X', default=1, validators=[
                                                                                    MaxValueValidator(10),
                                                                                    MinValueValidator(1)
                                                                                ])
    y_pos = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Позиция Y', default=1, validators=[
                                                                                    MaxValueValidator(10),
                                                                                    MinValueValidator(1)
                                                                                ])
    ship_position = models.CharField(verbose_name='Положение корабля', choices=POSITIONS,
                                     default=VERTICAL, max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Позиция корабля "{self.ship.title}" у пользователя {self.user.username}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Позиция'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Позиции'
        ordering = ('x_pos', 'y_pos')
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Positions


class PlacementForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Positions
        fields = ['ship', 'x_pos', 'y_pos', 'ship_position']
```

views.py

```
class PlacementView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'sea_battle/placement.html'
    form_class = PlacementForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('placement')

    def add_ship_position(self, **kwargs):
        ship = kwargs['ship']
        user = kwargs['user']
        ship_positions = {'horizontal': 'x_pos', 'vertical': 'y_pos'}
        ship_position = ship_positions[kwargs['ship_position']]
        kwargs[ship_position] = int(kwargs[ship_position])
        for i in range(ship.length - 1):
            kwargs[ship_position] += 1
            Positions(ship=ship,
                      x_pos=kwargs['x_pos'],
                      y_pos=kwargs['y_pos'],
                      ship_position=kwargs['ship_position'],
                      user=user).save()
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(ip=get_client_ip(self.request))
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = user
        self.add_ship_position(ship=self.object.ship, ship_position=self.object.ship_position,
                               user=self.object.user, x_pos=self.object.x_pos, y_pos=self.object.y_pos)
        self.object.save()
        return super(PlacementView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменить `queryset` поля формы можно переопределив `__init__` у этой формы.
Я бы добавил в модель `Ships` поле `is_exposed = BooleanField`, которое хранит информацию о том, выставлен ли корабль. По нажатию кнопки "Выставить", это поле должно принимать значение `True` и сохраняться в базу. Далее в нужную форму добавил бы примерно такой код:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'ship' in kwargs and kwargs['ship'] is not None:
        ship = kwargs.pop('ship')
        ship_qs = ship.filter(is_exposed=True)
        self.fields['ship'].queryset = ship_qs

    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```